# Is it possible to instantiate a WebServiceHost via an instance of the service type, without a parameterless constructor?

Tags: wcf, webservicehost

I am trying to create self-hosted `System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost` (.NET 4), however I am running into an issue with the constructor.  There are three options:

1. `WebServiceHost()` a parameterless constructor that seems pointless, as there's no way to specify the type of the service, or even the contract.  Reflecting on it, it doesn't do anything- just an empty default constructor that doesn't call base.
2. `WebServiceHost(object singletonInstance, params Uri[] baseAddresses)` I don't want a singleton instance, as this is a `InstanceContextMode.PerCall` class.
3. `WebServiceHost(System.Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)` The type I want to instantiate as a service doesn't have a parameterless constructor (which is a requirement of this method).  I'm using NInject to push the parameters into the constructor.  However, I'm trying to run this as a self-hosted test, so I want to avoid DI.

Are there any options along these lines, or will I have to not self-host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To support service classes without parameter-less constructors you need to use an `IInstanceProvider` implementation which knows how to create the service class. The code below shows one with the `WebServiceHost`, and you can find more about instance providers at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/31/wcf-extensibility-iinstanceprovider.aspx.

```
public class StackOverflow_9997163
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public class Service
    {
        private int increment;
        public Service(int increment)
        {
            this.increment = increment;
        }
        [WebGet]
        public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y + increment;
        }
    }
    class MyInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider
    {
        Func<Service> serviceCreator;
        public MyInstanceProvider(Func<Service> serviceCreator)
        {
            this.serviceCreator = serviceCreator;
        }

        public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
        {
            return this.serviceCreator();
        }

        public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            return this.serviceCreator();
        }

        public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
        {
        }
    }
    class MyServiceBehavior : IServiceBehavior
    {
        Func<Service> serviceCreator;
        public MyServiceBehavior(Func<Service> serviceCreator)
        {
            this.serviceCreator = serviceCreator;
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            foreach (ChannelDispatcher cd in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
            {
                foreach (EndpointDispatcher ed in cd.Endpoints)
                {
                    ed.DispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = new MyInstanceProvider(this.serviceCreator);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        int currentIncrement = 1;
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new MyServiceBehavior(delegate()
        {
            return new Service(currentIncrement++);
        }));
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            WebClient c = new WebClient();
            Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/Add?x=6&y=8"));
        }

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```